# Dynamic setter custom View

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view

I'm starting to create graphical components on Android and I'm facing a problem that is I suppose very simple.

The attributes passed to my custom layout are read and well recognized in XML.
However, I would like these attributes to be passed dynamically.

Here is my code:

```
    <declare-styleable name="MyAppBarLayout">
        <attr name="text" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

```
class MyAppBarLayout(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): AppBarLayout(context, attrs) {


    init {
        val view = inflate(context, R.layout.my_appbar, this)

        val attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyAppBarLayout)

        view.text_subtitle.text = attributes.getString(R.styleable.MyAppBarLayout_text)

        attributes.recycle()
    }

}
```

What I want to do with this view is this :

```
var myAppBar.text = "WARNING"
```

How can I set dynamic setters ?
I have looked at Google's documentation on this subject, but I don't understand if I should have an attribute corresponding to the property.

Comment: You are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/16183176/2413303 and a simple `var` with a `set(value) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is:

```
class MyAppBarLayout(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): AppBarLayout(context, attrs) {
    private var text: String? = null

    ...
    fun setText(text: String) {
        view.sutitle.text = text
    }
}

// wherever you want to set the text
var myAppBar.text = "WARNING"
```

The way you are doing is for setting the text(attribute) from layout xml.

Comment: I don't understand your code... If it's private I can't access it from an Activity

Comment: you can either make it public or have a setter for it. Will update the code with a setter function.